# Modelling multinomial dependent variable with longitudinal/panel data (R)

Tags: r, categorical-data, multinomial, multilevel-analysis, mlm

I'm having some trouble with an analyses I want to conduct and were wondering if there are any alternatives. Essentially I have a longitudinal dataset (or panel data), and a dependent variable (group membership) that is categorical and time invariant. For example:

| ID | Time | Group | Sex | Age | X1 | X2 | X3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | M | 23 | 4 | 6 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | A | M | 23 | 2 | 6 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | A | M | 23 | 3 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | B | F | 31 | 5 | 6 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | B | F | 31 | 5 | 7 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | B | F | 31 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | C | M | 27 | 4 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | C | M | 27 | 5 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 | C | M | 27 | 2 | 3 | 3 |

So we have both time invariant variables (Sex, Age) and time variant variables (X1, X2, X3), with our DV (Group) being constant within-person. Typically, I believe the correct analysis here would be a mixed multinomial logit regression, however I haven't found a way to run a model like that in R after attempting numerous packages.

I was wondering if there were other types of analyses that I could use to model Group membership. I have explored other analyses such as longitudinal discriminant analysis, but they tend to use binary outcomes, rather than multinomial. I have also looked at packages like "multgee" but the outcome variable in those packages is measured at every time point (whereas Group here is static across time).

Is there a package related to mixed multinomial models that I've missed, or another package I can use to account for this data structure/outcome variable? Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For this type of data, I think that a multinomial logit model would be appropriate. The coefficients in this case would represent the log-odds that an independent variable is associated with a change in an individual's group.

Regarding which packages you might consider, I'll point you to another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64044752/package-for-multivariate-multinomial-logit/65766154#65766154). Seems like `mlogit` will be your best bet for general purpose multinomial logit modeling, although `nnet` might be preferable if you prefer a mixed log-linear model.